# How to vary the size of piechart in d3 with tree layout

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to display a tree diagram with piechart as the nodes with the size of the piechart scaled according to data. I am still stump at the last part:

var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(20)

fix the radius at 20.

How can I vary it according to the "count" property. A jsfiddle demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/uB4U2/

The data is contained as:

```
var treeData = {"name" : "Root", "info" : "1", "count" : 9, "value" : [1,2,3], 
            "children" : [
           {"name" : "A", "info" : "2", "count" : 10, "value" : [2,2,2] }, 
           {"name" : "B", "info" : "3", "count" : 15, "value" : [2,2,2] }, 
           {"name" : "C", "info" : "4", "count" : 2, "value" : [2,2,2] , 
            "children": [
                {"name" : "C1", "info" : "5", "count" : 7, "value" : [2,3,4] }, 
                {"name" : "C2", "info" : "6", "count" : 8, "value" : [2,3,4] }
                    ]} 
            ]};
```

Thanks!

Comment: according to the count property you want to vary the radius right...?

Comment: @Manoj, yes that's what I would like to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example shows that you were trying to set the outerRadius based on a function of the data, but gave up and just set it to return a constant value:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(function(d) { console.log(d); return radius; });
```

The reason this wasn't working is because the data passed in to the arc generator is the data object for each individual *slice* in the pie.  This could be used, for example, to create a graph like this:
[image: A "Spie Chart"]

Cool, but not what you want.  You wanted to size the entire pie based on the total count, right?  However, that data isn't available directly to the arc function, which only has information about one slice at a time.  So you need to set the radius when the data for the whole pie *is* available -- when you are still working with the nodes.  Because we want to modify the arc generator function for the node and then use it when drawing the slices, we have to group everything for creating the pie into an `each()` method call:

```
node.each(function(d){
    arc = arc.outerRadius(d.count);

    d3.select(this)
    .selectAll("path")
        .data(function(d){ return pie(d.value); })
    .enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d,i){ return color(i) });    
})
```

With that change to your code, you get:
http://jsfiddle.net/uB4U2/3/

P.S.  I'm a little confused about your "count" properties, since the count for parents are sometimes smaller than the count for children.  If this isn't what you wanted, I hope it has given you enough information to figure out where to go from here.  --ABR

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation and code answered the question. Indeed, I was stuck when I realize the arc generator didn't have the count data. In my case, the "count" in children node is independent of the parent so can be larger.

Answer (score 0):

Create dynamic `radius` according to the maximum number of count.Try this code for maximum number

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/2PFCq/)**

**D3.js**:

```
  var Maxcount = new Array();
  $.each(nodes, function (i,value) {
          Maxcount.push(value.count);
       });
  radius =d3.max(Maxcount);
```

Comment: sorry, this is not what I wanted. I want the piechart at each node to have different sizes according to the count property at that node.

Comment: The question was not clear. Thats why its important to post completely clear question. It very bad if persons who wants to answer must guess the meaning of the question.